# Generate a contiguous period starting from two dates (for a pair of ID and Value)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm working with Oracle 11 and 
i need to rebuild period from table that has 2 date field and 2 fields: id and percent value.

If there is continuity between the dates (for each pair of ID and Value) I have to report only one line until the continuity is not interrupted.
Otherwise I report the period as read from the table.

I don't know if it can be done with pure SQL or I have to rely on a Cursor.

This is my Source Table

```
ID  PercValue   START_DATE  END_DATE
1   50  01/01/2014  01/03/2014
1   50  01/04/2014  01/05/2014
1   53  01/06/2014  01/07/2014
1   53  01/08/2014  02/01/2014
1   60  02/02/2014  02/10/2014
1   60  02/11/2014  02/28/2014
1   60  03/10/2014  03/15/2014
2   60  03/15/2014  03/31/2014
2   61  04/01/2014  04/29/2014
2   61  05/01/2014  06/30/2014
```

And This is my goal

```
ID  PercValue   START_DATE  END_DATE
1   50  01/01/2014  01/05/2019
1   53  01/06/2014  02/01/2019
1   60  02/02/2019  02/28/2019
1   60  03/10/2019  03/15/2019
2   60  03/15/2019  03/31/2019
2   61  04/01/2019  04/29/2019
2   61  05/01/2019  06/30/2019
```

Comment: This can be accomplished through pure SQL. I recommend reading up on the [Tabibitosan Method](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-915680). In your case (two dates per row), I believe the logic will look something like `end_date - SUM(end_date - start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY percvalue ORDER BY start_dt) AS grp`

Answer (score 0):

```
start_DATE >= to_date(substr(:from_date,1,10),'YYYY/MM/DD')
  end_DATE <= to_date(substr(:END_date,1,10),'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

use this as dates parametere